# Gitlab automated release via yaml

Tags: gitlab-ci-runner

I'm trying to automate the release creation of my project and I'm having some issue with the actual release script.

I have the following release node, which takes the artifacts from my build step and attempts to create a release page with it and a link to the built project executable, which is zipped in the
**dist/*.zip**

```
release:win-installer:
  stage: release
  tags:
     - docker
  image: registry.gitlab.com/gitlab-org/release-cli
  dependencies:
    - 'build:win-installer-tags'
  only:
    - /^*-rc$/
  script:
    - >
      release-cli create --name release-branch-$CI_JOB_ID --description release-   branch-$CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME-$CI_JOB_ID
        --tag-name "$CI_COMMIT_TAG"
        --description './CHANGELOG.md'
        --ref "$CI_COMMIT_SHA"
        --assets-link '{"name": "Flight Assistant - Next Generation", "url":"https://gitlab.com/quadsat1/software/flightassistant-nextgen/-/jobs/$CI_JOB_ID/artifacts/download", "link_type":"other","filepath":"dist/*.zip"}'
  artifacts:
    name: 'release $CI_COMMIT_TAG'
    paths:
      - dist/*.zip
    expire_in: never
```

When this node runs however, I receive the following error code:[image]

Up until this point everything runs smoothly, for some reason however the job tries to open a **/build** folder by default, a folder which does not exist.

How can I get rid of this error message and have my release done with an added assets link to the project executable?

I chose to do this via script keyword because doing with with the release keyword meant I could not add assets-link to it. I looked in the documentation and couldn't find any syntax for adding the assets-link in that way.

Answer (score 0):

It seems I jumped the gun. The issue was caused by bad indentation on the release command. Removing the two white spaces in front of the lines 2-5 of the script command solved it.